# What is a usual workflow for dealing with shared files with capistrano?

Tags: ruby, database, capistrano

My `.csv` recreates on every release, and, as I understand, to keep its data unchanged between deploys I need to put it in `/shared` directory and simlink to it from my `deploy.rb`.
Is this the right route? (I have this question because I don't seem to find much info on how to do this with respect to, eg, databases, for some reason. `/shared` directory is mostly used for `.conf` files and paperclip-like directories).

Comment: The reason you don't find anything on this, is that it is very unconventional to create a new database on every release. And I'm wondering why one would need this ;-) If you just 'don't recreate it every release' you will automatically keep the data.

Comment: yep that's the point, I need my production database to persist between releases. and it doesn't. because I fill it up in production, then deploy another release and my filled up database stays in a previous release.

Comment: I think it is a good approach to use a `.csv` or`.yaml` file to transport the data into the new relase. A dogmatic way to import such data would be to use the `db:seed` task provided by rails. You can use capistrano to call ist after your deployment

Answer (score 1):

When using capistrano, your application code will be "uploaded" to some directory on the server. Capistrano uses this structure:
/path_to_folder:
  current - symlink to the directory with the current release
  releases - contains all kept releases
  shared   - files that should persist between releases

So to your question - copy the .csv file somewhere into "shared" directory and then in the config/deploy.rb add this:

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :create_symlinks do
    run "ln -s #{shared_path}/something.csv #{latest_release}/db/something.csv"
  end
end

after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:create_symlinks'
```

Replace "something" with the file name that you copied. You can also put the csv file into some directory under "shared" if you want to, I'd use "db" in this case. If you do so, don't forget to update path in the symlink.

Comment: aha. so on every deploy we will be creating a new symbolic link to preeexistent csv file somewhere in `/shared`. thanks for clearing up my confusion.